# how to create and use a new Python class that inherits from list

Tags: python, list, class, inheritance

I am trying to create a simple class that inherits from `list`, but I'm not quite sure if I'm using it correctly. My class is defined as follows:

```
class pairs(list):

    def __init__(
        self,
        *args
        ):
        # list initialisation
        super().__init__(self, *args)   

    def update(updatePairs):
        for updatePair in range(len(updatePairs)):
            found_match = False

            for pair in range(len(self)):
                # If there is a matching 'key' in a pair of the existing list of
                # pairs, record that a match was found and update the existing
                # pair.
                if updatePairs[updatePair][0] == self[pair][0]:
                    found_match   = True
                    self[pair][1] = updatePairs[updatePair][1]

            # If a matching 'key' is not found, there is no pair to update.
            # Append the update pair to the existing list of pairs.
            if not found_match:
                self.append(updatePairs[updatePair])
```

When I try to instantiate it, I run into a little difficulty because the initialisation method of the `list` class is expecting at least one argument:

```
>>> a = pairs.pairs()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "pairs.py", line 7, in __init__
    # list initialisation
TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
```

What am I doing wrong here? Am I instantiating the object incorrectly? Should I be using the initialisation method of the `list` class in a different way?

Comment: If this is Python 2.x, you need `super(pairs, self).__init__(...)`. Also, see [the docs on emulating containers](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-container-types).

Comment: Ah, that's it. I was writing for Python 3. I've added a check for the appropriate Python version together with the appropriate procedures: ```if sys.version_info >= (3, 0): super().__init__(self, *args); else: super(pairs, self).__init__(self, *args)```. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Python 3 will handle `super(pairs, self)` just fine, so if you're writing for both I'd just use that. Also, note that you can check `sys.version_info.major >= 3`.